# Set default screen based on return value in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

My App has three screens, on running the App the first screen is always the same screen, on running the app, I need it to display different screens based on the return values of a specific function.

I have the UI to change screens and a function that returns a numerical value, based on this logic the screens should change.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window


class ScreenMain(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_main_id = ObjectProperty()
    screen_one_id = ObjectProperty()
    screen_two_id = ObjectProperty()


class ScreenmainApp(App):

    def build(self):
    '''This method returns the Manager class'''
        self.auth()
        return Manager()

    def auth(self):
    '''This function is called by build(), return
    value should determine which screen is displayed on running the App,
    by default the MAIN SCREEN IS FIRST SHOWN'''

        a = 3
        b = 5
        value = a + b
        if value >0 <= 5:
            print('Show screen 1')
        elif value >5<=10:
            print('Show screen 2')
        else:
            print('Show main screen')
        print('This is the return value: ',value)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    ScreenmainApp().run()
```

### screenmain.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:include screenone.kv
#:include screentwo.kv

<Manager>:
    screen_main: screen_main_id
    screen_one: screen_one_id
    screen_two: screen_two_id

# The order below determines which screen is displayed after app loads
    ScreenMain:
        id: screen_main_id
        name: 'ScreenMain'

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one_id
        name: 'Screen1'

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two_id
        name: 'Screen2'

<ScreenMain>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text:"WELCOME TO THE MAIN SCREEN"
        Button:
            text:'Go to Screen 1'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
        Button:
            text:'Go to Screen 2'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen2'
        Label:
```

### screenone.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'This is SCREEN ONE'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: "Go to Screen 2"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen2'
            Button:
                text: "Back to Home"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'ScreenMain'
```

### screentwo.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'This is SCREEN TWO'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'            
            Button:
                text: "Go to Screen 1"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
            Button:
                text: "Go to Home"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'ScreenMain'
```

Actual results: On App load up, the main screen always shows up first.
Expected results: Based on the value returned in auth() the screens are supposed to change each time on running the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is instantiate the `ScreenManager` before calling `self.auth()` method.

## Snippets

```
def build(self):

    '''This method returns the Manager class'''
    self.root = Manager()
    self.auth()
    return self.root

def auth(self):

    '''This function is called by build(), return
    value should determine which screen is displayed on running the App,
    by default the MAIN SCREEN IS FIRST SHOWN'''

    a = 3
    b = 5
    value = a + b
    if value > 0 <= 5:
        print('Show screen 1')
        self.root.current = 'Screen1'
    elif value > 5 <= 10:
        print('Show screen 2')
        self.root.current = 'Screen2'
    else:
        print('Show main screen')
        self.root.current = 'ScreenMain'
    print('This is the return value: ', value)
```

Comment: Instantiation, a simple thing I overlooked, thanks @ikolim as always :)